# Plot time series with known error (ggplot2)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series, errorbar

I'm working with American Community Survey (ACS) 1-year estimates for a specific location over several years. For example, I'm trying to plot how the proportion of men and women riding a bike to work changes over time. From the ACS, I get estimates and standard error, which I can then use to calculate the upper and lower bounds of the estimates.

So the simplified data structure in wide format is like this:

```
| Year | EstimateM | MaxM | MinM | EstimateF | MaxF | MinF |
|------|-----------|------|------|-----------|------|------|
| 2005 | 3.0       | 3.5  | 2.5  | 2.0       | 2.3  | 1.7  |
| 2006 | 3.1       | 3.5  | 2.6  | 2.0       | 2.3  | 1.7  |
| 2007 | 5.0       | 4.2  | 5.8  | 2.5       | 3.0  | 2.0  |
| ...  | ...       | ...  | ...  | ...       | ...  | ...  |
```

If I only wanted to plot the estimates, I'd `melt` the data with only the two `Estimate` variables as `measure.vars`

```
GenderModeCombined_long <- melt(GenderModeCombined,
                            id = "Year",
                            measure.vars = c("EstimateM",
                                             "EstimateF")
```

The long data can then be easily plotted with `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(data=GenderModeCombined_long,
  aes(x=year, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

This produces a graph like so

[image: Imgur]

(sorry, don't have enough rep to post images)

Where I'm stuck is how to add error bars to the two estimate graphs. I could add them as `measure vars` to the melted dataset, but then how do I tell ggplot what should be plotted as values and what as error bars? Do I have to create a separate data frame with just the min/max data and then load that separately?

```
geom_errorbar(data = errordataMmax, aes(ymax = ??, ymin = ??))
```

I have the feeling that I'm somehow approaching this the wrong way and/or have my data set up the wrong way.

Comment: If you can make this question reproducible, you are much more likely to get a useful answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. The problem here is that you have three "explicit" variables (Estimate, 
Min and Max) and an "implicit" one (gender) which is coded in column names. A way to solve this is to make "gender" an explicit grouping variable. After you go to long format, create a "gender" variable, remove the indication of gender from the key column (variable) and then go back to wide format.
Something like this would work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

GenderModeCombined <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,   ~EstimateM,   ~MaxM,   ~MinM,   ~EstimateF,   ~MaxF,   ~MinF,  
  2005,         3.0,    3.5,    2.5,         2.0,    2.3,    1.7,  
  2006,         3.1,    3.5,    2.6,         2.0,    2.3,    1.7,  
  2007,         5.0,    4.2,    5.8,         2.5,    3.0,    2.0
)

GenderModeCombined.long <- GenderModeCombined %>% 
  # switch to long format
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -Year,  factor_key = TRUE) %>% 
  # add a gender variable
  dplyr::mutate(gender   = stringr::str_sub(variable, -1)) %>% 
  # remove gender indication from the key column `variable`
  dplyr::mutate(variable = stringr::str_sub(variable, end = -2)) %>%
  # back to wide format
  tidyr::spread(variable, value)

GenderModeCombined.long
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    Year gender Estimate   Max   Min
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2005 F           2     2.3   1.7
#> 2  2005 M           3     3.5   2.5
#> 3  2006 F           2     2.3   1.7
#> 4  2006 M           3.1   3.5   2.6
#> 5  2007 F           2.5   3     2  
#> 6  2007 M           5     4.2   5.8

ggplot(data=GenderModeCombined.long,
       aes(x=Year, y=Estimate,colour = gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Max, ymin = Min))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: The lines are missing from the chart because `Year` is of type character which is treated as discrete variable by `ggplot2`. Is there a specific reason to  pass all numeric data as type character to `tibble::tribble()`?

Comment: no reason at all. Just cut and paste laziness... I amended the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! So the block was indeed in the data structure -- I just couldn't wrap my head around how to fix it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As explained by [lbusett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964441/3817004), the answer to this question is not so much about plotting but about reshaping the data from wide to long form. The challenge here is that there are multiple value columns, i.e., `Estimate`, `Max`, `Min`, for each gender.

As of version v1.9.6 (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015), [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s incarnation of the `melt()` function allows for melting, i.e., reshaping from wide to long format, into multiple columns in one go:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
cols <- c("Estimate", "Max", "Min")
long <- melt(setDT(GenderModeCombined), id.vars = "Year", measure.vars = patterns(cols), 
             value.name = cols, variable.name = "Gender")[
               , Gender := forcats::lvls_revalue(Gender, c("M", "F"))][]
long
```

> ```
>     Year Gender Estimate   Max   Min
>    <int> <fctr>    <num> <num> <num>
> 1:  2005      M      3.0   3.5   2.5
> 2:  2006      M      3.1   3.5   2.6
> 3:  2007      M      5.0   4.2   5.8
> 4:  2005      F      2.0   2.3   1.7
> 5:  2006      F      2.0   2.3   1.7
> 6:  2007      F      2.5   3.0   2.0
> ```

Now, we have three observations per `Year` and `Gender` which can be plotted as desired:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long, aes(x = Year, y = Estimate, colour = Gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Max, ymin = Min), width = 0.1)
```

[image]

Please, note that this chart shows also lines in addition to points and error bars. This is because `Year` is of type *integer* which is recognized by `ggplot2` as continuous variable.

#### Data

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s `fread()` function is very handy to read various data formats. So, we can read the data as posted by the OP with only a few modifications:

```
library(data.table)
GenderModeCombined <- fread(
"| Year | EstimateM | MaxM | MinM | EstimateF | MaxF | MinF |
| 2005 | 3.0       | 3.5  | 2.5  | 2.0       | 2.3  | 1.7  |
| 2006 | 3.1       | 3.5  | 2.6  | 2.0       | 2.3  | 1.7  |
| 2007 | 5.0       | 4.2  | 5.8  | 2.5       | 3.0  | 2.0  |
", drop = c(1L, 9L))

GenderModeCombined
```

> ```
>     Year EstimateM  MaxM  MinM EstimateF  MaxF  MinF
>    <int>     <num> <num> <num>     <num> <num> <num>
> 1:  2005       3.0   3.5   2.5       2.0   2.3   1.7
> 2:  2006       3.1   3.5   2.6       2.0   2.3   1.7
> 3:  2007       5.0   4.2   5.8       2.5   3.0   2.0
> ```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works for me as well. @lbusett 's code with `tidyverse` is a little easier for me to read, but good to know that it can also be done with `melt`